# How can I re-enable ASLR?

Tags: kernel

For some buffer overflow tests, I disabled ASLR in Ubuntu 14.04 using this command:

```
echo "0" >/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

However, after I tried to enable it again, the program I've written runs in the same address space layout every time.

I have used the below values to enable it again, but ASLR is not working any more (its default was 2 in my system):

```
echo "2" >/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
echo "1" >/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Answer (score 2):

According to what brought in [How Effective is ASLR on Linux Systems?](http://securityetalii.es/2013/02/03/how-effective-is-aslr-on-linux-systems/), programs must be compiled as Position Independent Executable ([PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)) to gain ASLR benefits.

For the GCC compiler, the `-fPIE` switch should be used to compile programs which use ASLR:

```
gcc -fPIE -o ./test.o  test.c^
```